# Coordinate reference system for wide areas in Canada

Tags: coordinate-system, canada, ellipsoid

I am using imagery from different sensors (Sentinel 2 and high resolution satellite) in several areas in Canada. I am trying to accurately represent areas (polygons), however when merging information from different sensors I observed small displacements which I cannot explain. Which is the recommended CRS to be used in Canada to minimize deformations?